# Printing(echo) even with null values

Tags: php, sql-server, select, datatable

so i have 4 tables in which two of them have null values which i believe is the reason for "Catchable fatal error: Object of class variant could not be converted to string".

my tables are

```
table1(dbo.FA_PC)  
FAID(pk)  
PCID(fk)  

table2(dbo.PC)  
PCID(PK)  
PCCPUTypeID(fk)(some values are null/empty)  

table3(dbo.PC_CPU_Type)  
PCCPUTypeID(PK)  
CPU  
BrandID(fk)(some values are null/empty)  

table4(Brand)  
BrandID(PK)  
Brand
```

so my code and select statement goes like this

```
<?php
$faidf=$_POST['faidf'];
ini_set("display_errors","on");
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
   try {
   $myServer = "WTCPHFILESRV\WTCPHINV";
   $myUser = "sa";
   $myPass = "P@ssw0rd";
   $myDB = "wtcphitinventory";   
   $connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=".$myServer.";UID=".$myUser.";PWD=".$myPass.";DATABASE=".$myDB;
   $conn->open($connStr); 
         if (! $conn) {
            throw new Exception("Could not connect!");
        }
   }

   catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Error (File:): ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
   }
if (!$conn)
  {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
   $sql_exp = "SELECT  c.CPU, d.Brand
FROM    dbo.FA_PC a
        INNER JOIN dbo.PC b
        on a.PCID = b.PCID
        INNER JOIN dbo.PC_CPU_Type c
            ON b.PCCPUTypeID = c.PCCPUTypeID    
        INNER JOIN dbo.Brand d
            ON c.BrandID = d.BrandID
WHERE   a.FAID = $faidf AND c.PCCPUTypeID is NOT NULL and c.BrandID is NOT NULL";    
   $rs = $conn->Execute($sql_exp);  
    echo "<tr><td>".$rs->Fields("Brand")."-".$rs->Fields("CPU")."</td>";

       $rs->Close();      
?>
```

is my where statement wrong or my select statement is a little off or what causes the error of "Catchable fatal error: Object of class variant could not be converted to string "

Comment: Hm, hope this aren't your _actual_ database credentials. In case they are, you can do so much better than `P@ssw0rd`...

Comment: Can you please highlight the row that is throwing the error?

Comment: You are passing `$faidf` unescaped (probably nothing to do with the error, but should be pointed out).

Comment: the printing(echo) part has the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `$rs->Fields("Brand")` is returning object which is not of string type and you're trying to concatenate it as if it was string. First you have to cast this object to string or access some property of this object that holds the string data you require.

Instead of `$rs->Fields("Brand")` try fetching the field data like this:

```
$rs->fields["Brand"]->value
```

Try traversing the records like this:

```
while (!$rs->EOF){ 
  echo '<tr><td>'.$rs->fields["Brand"]->value.'-'.$rs->fields["CPU"]->value.'</td></tr>'; 
  $rs->movenext(); 
}
```

Comment: brand is just pure text and doesnt have any other type though the $rs->Fields("CPU") eg I3, I5, I7 have numbers on it. how could i cast it into string?

Comment: It seems that you're not looping through records appropriately, I added some sample code, hope it helps...

Comment: thank you it works. i got the same codes from my other programs yet i was flustered due to panic xD thanks